# Clear drawn gdiplus rectangle

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

I'm drawing a semi-transparent rectangle with gdiplus over all windows in a loop, for each cycle the rectangle loses its transparency. How do I clear the previously drawn rectangle or keep it with the same transparency value?
I need to display the rectangle on top of all apps.

Draw code:

```
Gdiplus::Graphics g(desktopHDC);
Gdiplus::SolidBrush brush(Gdiplus::Color(50 /*A*/, 0 /*R*/, 0 /*G*/, 255 /*B*/));
g.FillRectangle(&brush, 0, 0, 100, 100);
```

I tried clearing the Graphics object with transparent color, but it just turned my screen black. I also tried to InvilidateRect but it didn't do anything.

Comment: There are literally *hundreds* of questions here that try to do the same thing. The answer doesn't change: You cannot reliably render into a window that's not yours. A window belongs to whoever called `CreateWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

This won't fly since with the draw you change the desktop image and don't have simple way back (if you don't want to hold/fetch areas which is a bad idea again for the dynamic image of desktop).

The simplest way to achieve what you need is to create a transparent window for the entire screen and draw on it.

See [UpdateLayeredWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatelayeredwindow?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more details.

Comment: I was able to clear it when I drew non-transparent rect and used SetPixel on desktop window, is there a way to draw rectangles with transparency without using gdi?

Comment: (1) I am not sure that your question is correct and that is what you want to ask. Of course, there are; DirectX, OpenGL, etc. Do you mean that you want do so without gdiplus with gdi only? What do you want to achieve exactly? (2) I understand that you were able to clear it, but is it the desired result? As I understand, you clear the whole desktop with it, isn't it?

Comment: What I want is to draw objects (rectangle or a single pixel) on top of any foreground window. The setpixel method worked fine, I cleared them with InvilidateRect (the screen didn't turn black or flicker). But I couldn't find a way to display them with transparency. The only way I found is to use gdiplus (setpixel is standart windows.h), but it turns out there's no way to clear the objects drawn with gdiplus.

Comment: (1) This is totally unclear from your question. You say in it that you can draw transparent rectangle and it loses transparency with each cycle. This is opposite to "But I couldn't find a way to display them with transparency". Could you specify more precisely what you get and what is missing? (2) Would [Setting the Alpha Values of Individual Pixels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-setting-the-alpha-values-of-individual-pixels-use) work for you?

Comment: When I drew transparent rectangles with gdiplus, with each cycle it overlapped with itself making it less and less transparent. I just want a way to prevent it, to make the rectangle always stay with the same transparency. The link you provided draws the gdiplus bitmap, which I still don't know how to clear.

Comment: Any hdc (including made for bitmap, see [CreateDIBSection function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdibsection) ) could be cleared with [FillRect function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-fillrect). gdiplus context could be cleared with [Graphics::Clear method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusgraphics/nf-gdiplusgraphics-graphics-clear). Again, I am not sure that clearing of desktop is what you want to get.

Comment: @SinusoidalDepleneration You will want to cooperate with the desktop compositor, not fight it. A proper solution to your problem has been outlined here: [High-Performance Window Layering Using the Windows Composition Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/june/windows-with-c-high-performance-window-layering-using-the-windows-composition-engine).

Comment: @IInspectable, good article, but is this dramatically different from what I posted in the answer with the "The simplest way to achieve what you need is to create a transparent window for the entire screen and draw on it." and link to the [UpdateLayeredWindow ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatelayeredwindow?redirectedfrom=MSDN) below despite the fact that in the article it is not used directly? If so, could you please, pinpoint the key differences?

Comment: The link above doesn't provide a substantially different strategy at solving the issue. It merely outlines an alternative way to implement the same solution. If you create a window that covers the entire desktop area, then that allocates a *lot* of render surface memory. For compatibility with the GDI, the system needs to allocate two of those surfaces. The suggested alternative simply drops GDI support (`WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP`) and uses a single surface that is immediately accessible to the desktop compositor.